# Can't get an image to display in EJS within Node and Express

Tags: node.js, express

I am currently new to Node and Express, so I apologize if this is a simple fix.  I cannot seem to get my image to load with the ejs site when running my node server.

My folders are structured like this:

```
-Project
  -public
    -images
      -image.png
      -project_1.jpg
    -scripts
    -styles
  -views
    -partials
      -header.ejs
    -index.ejs
  -app.js
```

In my app.js I have

```
app.use(express.static("public"));
```

And in my index.ejs I have:

```
<div>
  <img id="my-image" src="images/image.png" alt="image">
</div>
```

I have tried changing this to /images/image.png and I have had no luck in getting this to work.

However, on another part of my ejs, I have:

```
<div>
  <img src="images/project_1.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="Project 1">
</div>
```

And THIS image loads without an issue, even though the directories are exactly the same.

Does someone know where my code is not able to retrieve the first image?  Thanks.

Comment: could the css be preventing it from showing?

Comment: What HTTP response do you get?

Comment: See [Path problem - absolute vs. relative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60825579/path-problem-in-url-absolute-and-relative/61392843#61392843) for likely explanation.  Don't use relative paths (paths that don't start with `/`) for static resources.  Also, see [Page URL affecting the serviing of static resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41991526/url-affecting-the-serving-of-static-files-when-using-express/41991665#41991665)

Comment: Here's another good reference: [Express static not serving files form public folders in paths that are not `/`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60714452/express-static-not-serving-files-from-public-folders-in-router-paths-that-are/60714526#60714526)

Comment: Thank you so much for your references!  I cannot believe it was so simple, but this issue was because I did not have the proper capitalization in the file name.  I originally built this in HTML as a static page on my local pc.  I guess capitalization doesn't matter there?  Thanks.